# How do I match a message with a newline in log4net with the stringToMatch filter?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm having trouble with configuring a [`StringMatchFilter`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#filters) to match a
string in a message with newlines. I want to skip some messages and I
have added a filter like this and it works.

```xml
<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
  <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false" />
  <stringToMatch value="Unexpected exception in SocketThreadWorker" />
</filter>
```

But if I change the `stringToMatch` to "An existing connection was
forcibly closed by the remote host" which occurs on the second row of
the message the filter does not work. Is it because of the newline in
the message or am I doing anything wrong here?

A typical message can look like this:

------ Example message ----------------------------

```
2011-05-04 16:22:24,078 [Client (connected from "127.0.0.1:4076" at 16:22)] ERROR - Unexpected exception in SocketThreadWorker System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

------ End example message ---------------------------

"Unexpected exception in SocketThreadWorker" is on the first row of the message and "An existing connection was forcibly closed" is on the second row.

**Edit**

The appender looks like this:

```xml
<appender name="SmtpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender">
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
    <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="false" /> 
    <stringToMatch value="An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" />        
  </filter>
  <to value="..." />
  <from value="..." />
  <subject value="[... ${COMPUTERNAME}] An Error occurred" />
  <smtpHost value=".." />
  <bufferSize value="1024" />
  <lossy value="true" />
  <evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
     <threshold value="ERROR"/>
  </evaluator>
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%newline%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I don't want to notify anybody about this error message since it is really not that serious. The message is not produced by my own code but it comes from a library that I use.

Comment: Can you please post your log4net configuration section?

Comment: And based on my answer, it might be nice to have the code that produces this log statement.

Comment: Also, because I think the problem is not "fixable" can you post what you want to accomplish (in general terms, not in terms of log4net) so that we can think up alternatives?

Comment: Daniel, can you come back and accept an answer?

Answer (score 15):

## Explanation of log4net Appending

The `SocketThreadWorker` is throwing a [`SocketException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.aspx). The exception message, "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", is mapped by the [error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668%28VS.85%29.aspx).

```
throw new SocketException(10054);
```

The code producing the log statement looks like an unhandled exception handler (by the message printed "Unexpected exception... "). But, for this answer, imagine it looks like this

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _log.Error("Unexpected exception in SocketThreadWorker", e);
}
```

What log4net produces under the covers is a [`LoggingEvent`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.LoggingEvent.html). It contains the provided log message and the exception object (separately). Each appender can decide how to write these two items to their final destinations (along with other properties, layout parameters, etc).

The `StringToMatch` filter works only on the log message. Not on the exception message! Check out this code below, we'll construct a system and a test that will help us debug the problem

## Reproduction and Deep Dive

Here is a simple socket exception throwing class

```
public class SocketThreadWorker
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        throw new SocketException(10054);
    }
}
```

We'll configure log4net to use a `ConsoleAppender` with a string match filter, matching the exception message string.

```
public static class LocalLoggingConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        var filter = new StringMatchFilter
        {
            StringToMatch = "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host",
            AcceptOnMatch = false,
        };

        var appender = new ConsoleAppender
        {
            Layout = new SimpleLayout()
        };

        appender.AddFilter(filter);

        BasicConfigurator.Configure(appender);
    }
}
```

We configure log4net, get a logger, and make a failing call in the test. You'll notice a few log statements at other levels and another one at `Error` that won't match our filter (if it works). This way, we can be sure that we're not accidentally losing *all* messages.

```
[TestClass]
public class SocketLibraryTest
{
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SocketLibraryTest));

    public SocketLibraryTest()
    {
        LocalLoggingConfiguration.Configure();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CatchThatPeskyException()
    {
        _log.Debug("Testing...");

        try
        {
            new SocketThreadWorker().DoWork();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _log.Info("An exception!");
            _log.Error("Unexpected exception in SocketThreadWorker", e);
            _log.Error("It wasn't that bad.");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this test, in my environment, includes the exception on a separate line from the message, because, by default, an appender will print the exception object that way.

```
DEBUG - Testing...  
INFO - An exception!  
ERROR - Unexpected exception in SocketThreadWorker  
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host  
   at SO5894291.SocketThreadWorker.DoWork() in d:\users\anthony.mastrean\documents\Projects\SO5894291\SO5894291\SocketLibraryTest.cs:line 16  
   at SO5894291.SocketLibraryTest.CatchThatPeskyException() in d:\users\anthony.mastrean\documents\Projects\SO5894291\SO5894291\SocketLibraryTest.cs:line 58  
ERROR - It wasn't that bad.
```

If you modify the appender filter to match on a part of a different message, you'll see that it is configured properly and does work. Change the string to match to "Testing" and you'll see the `DEBUG` statement disappear from the Console output!

## Recommendations

You do not want to match on the generic log message "An unexpected exception... ". That has the chance to lose messages. Even introducting a logger match filter won't help, because that socket worker probably can and will throw other exceptions (again, potentially losing messages).

The only option I can think of is to implement your own `ExceptionMessageToMatchFilter`. I've copied the implementation of `StringToMatchFilter`, replacing the rendered message string for the exception message.

```
public class ExceptionMessageToMatchFilter : StringMatchFilter
{
    public override FilterDecision Decide(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        if (loggingEvent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("loggingEvent");

        if (loggingEvent.ExceptionObject == null)
            return FilterDecision.Neutral;

        var exceptionMessage = loggingEvent.GetExceptionString();

        if (m_regexToMatch != null)
        {
            if (!m_regexToMatch.Match(exceptionMessage).Success)
                return FilterDecision.Neutral;

            return m_acceptOnMatch ? FilterDecision.Accept : FilterDecision.Deny;
        }

        if (m_stringToMatch == null || exceptionMessage.IndexOf(m_stringToMatch) == -1)
        {
            return FilterDecision.Neutral;
        }

        return m_acceptOnMatch ? FilterDecision.Accept : FilterDecision.Deny;
    }
}
```

I would be careful around the `GetExceptionString()` call, I don't know if it can return `null`. Or what you want to do if there is no message (is it empty? should you return neutral or continue matching?).

It's quite easy to rig up in your log4net configuration (especially because it has all the properties from the string to match filter).

```
<filter type="MyNamespace.ExceptionMessageToMatchFilter, MyAssembly">
    <stringToMatch value="An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" />
    <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

Comment: As you can see from the appender i added it is just the message that is and not the exception. I don't have access to the code that produces the log statement atm. Any more ideas?

Comment: A comment about the downvote would be helpful. How can you downvote an answer that I _verified with code?_

Comment: Very useful answer! Just implemented your logger class because I had to filter on the Exception.

Comment: Just wanted to correct a few things.  In the last bit where you are configuring the new filter, the XML node should be "filter" and not "appender".  Also the assembly should simply be "MyAssembly" and not "MyAssembly.dll".